# JAVA Wrong output in object array program (beginner)

Tags: java

I have an assignment to calculate the amount of carbon dioxide produced in a year from 
a household and compare how recycling can reduce its CO2 Footprint.
There are two classes in the program, CO2FromWaste, and CO2FromWasteTester.

The first class, CO2FromWaste is:

```
public class CO2FromWaste
{
    //declaration of private instance variables
    private int numPeople;
    private boolean Paper, Plastic, Glass, Cans;
    private double grossWasteEmission, wasteReduction, netWasteReduction;

    //constructor 
    CO2FromWaste(int people, boolean paper, boolean plastic, boolean glass, boolean cans){
        numPeople = people;
        Paper = paper;
        Plastic = plastic;
        Glass = glass;
        Cans = cans;
        grossWasteEmission = 0.0;
        wasteReduction = 0.0;
        netWasteReduction = 0.0;
    }
    public void calcGrossWasteEmission(){
        grossWasteEmission = numPeople * 1018;

    }
    public double getGrossWasteEmission(){
        return grossWasteEmission;
    }
    public void calcWasteReduction(){
        if (Paper == true){
            wasteReduction = numPeople * 184;
        }
        if (Plastic == true){
            wasteReduction += (numPeople * 25.6);
        }
        if (Glass == true){
            wasteReduction+= (numPeople*46.6);
        }
        if (Cans == true){
            wasteReduction+=(numPeople*165.8);
        }

    }
    public double getWasteReduction()
    {
        return wasteReduction;
    }
    public void calcNetWasteReduction(){
        netWasteReduction = grossWasteEmission = wasteReduction;

    }
    public double getNetWasteReduction(){
        return netWasteReduction;
    }
    public int getNumPeople(){
        return numPeople;
    }
    public boolean getPaper(){
        return Paper;
    }
    public boolean getPlastic(){
        return Plastic;
    }
    public boolean getGlass(){
        return Glass;
    }
    public boolean getCans(){
        return Cans;
    }
}
```

The second class, CO2FromWasteTester is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CO2FromWasteTester
{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        ArrayList<CO2FromWaste> waste = new ArrayList<CO2FromWaste>();

        waste.add(new CO2FromWaste(1, true, true, true, true));
        waste.add(new CO2FromWaste(3, true, false, true, true));
        waste.add(new CO2FromWaste(4, false, false, false, false));
        waste.add(new CO2FromWaste(1, true, true, true, true));
        waste.add(new CO2FromWaste(1, true, true, true, true));

        CO2FromWaste wasteRecord;
        for (int index = 0; index < waste.size(); index++){
            wasteRecord = waste.get(index);
            wasteRecord.calcGrossWasteEmission();
            wasteRecord.calcWasteReduction();
            wasteRecord.calcNetWasteReduction();
        }
        System.out.println("                   Household Waste Recycled                    Total    Pounds of CO2    Net");
        System.out.println(" Index    People    Paper     Plastic     Glass     Cans     Emission     Reduction    Emission ");

        for (int index = 0; index < waste.size(); index ++)
        {
            wasteRecord = waste.get(index);
            System.out.printf("%3d %9d %10s %10s %10s %10s %12.2f %10.2f %10.2f%n",index,wasteRecord.getNumPeople(),wasteRecord.getPaper(), wasteRecord.getPlastic(), wasteRecord.getGlass(),wasteRecord.getCans(),wasteRecord.getGrossWasteEmission(),wasteRecord.getWasteReduction(),wasteRecord.getNetWasteReduction());
        }
    }
}
```

The output should read like a table, with the correct data under the headers. 
For the first line, the output should be

```
0   1   true   true   true   true   1018.00   422.00   596.00
```

but it reads

```
0  1   true   true   true   true    422.00   422.00   422.00
```

There is something wrong starting the the gross emission part, and that part should be fairly simple because all it needs to do is to multiply the number of people given by 1018. 
I am not sure what to do from here and would appreciate some help.

Comment: The code you've given won't compile - `calcGrossWasteEmission` in `CO2FromWaste` has a parameter (`numPeople`) but you're calling it without any arguments. Therefore, this *isn't* the code you're running. Show us the code you're running, and we're much more likely to be able to find the problem...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete the parameter. It was testing some things to try to figure out the problem, but forgot to delete it when posting it on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public void calcNetWasteReduction(){
    netWasteReduction = grossWasteEmission = wasteReduction;    
}
```

That's equivalent to:

```
public void calcNetWasteReduction(){
    grossWasteEmission = wasteReduction;    
    netWasteReduction = grossWasteEmission;
}
```

In other words, it's modifying `grossWasteEmission` when it shouldn't be. I suspect you wanted:

```
public void calcNetWasteReduction(){
    netWasteReduction = grossWasteEmission - wasteReduction;    
}
```

In other words, making the second `=` a `-` instead.

It's not clear why you have the three separate methods at all, to be honest - why not perform the calculations in the constructor? Or in the `getter` methods (removing the intermediate fields altogether)?

Additionally, consider making an enum of waste reduction types (PAPER, GLASS, PLASTIC) and taking an `EnumSet` of them. If you *do* keep them as individual parameters, I would strongly advise you to change the names to be more conventional Java (`paper` instead of `Paper` etc) and use `if (paper)` rather than `if (paper == true)` etc. In general, avoid explicit checking against Boolean constants.

Comment: Wow I don't know how I didn't notice that. I changed it in to a minus sign, but now all the numbers read 0.0. Maybe there's something wrong with my calculations (when doing if statements)

Comment: @alphamonkey: I've run your exact code having changed the `=` to a `-`, and the *only* 0 in the output is the "reduction" part of index 2. I suspect you've made other changes which have broken it in other ways.

Comment: Never mind... I had accidentally deleted the calc() parts of CO2WasteTester. Everything works now! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for (int index = 0; index < waste.size(); index++){
    wasteRecord = waste.get(index);
    wasteRecord.calcGrossWasteEmission();
    wasteRecord.calcWasteReduction();
    wasteRecord.calcNetWasteReduction(); // <== netWasteReduction = grossWasteEmission = wasteReduction;
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem is in `calcNetWasteReduction` itself - not in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the '=' sign below. Its because of this line that you are getting all the three values equal.  :-)

public void calcNetWasteReduction(){
    netWasteReduction = grossWasteEmission **=** wasteReduction;

Hope this helps